# what happens when I cast a glm::vec3* to a double*?

Tags: c++, arrays, casting, glm-math

I am trying to understand a framework I have been provided with and slowly debugging it. In my case I have an array of vec3, memorized with a pointer

```
vec3 *cx =....;
```

First of all, every time I try to check the content of a glm::vec3 through debugging I see many values: x, r, s, y, g, t, z, b, p. I don't know why I have all these members, and according to the documentation I see that glm::vec3 is a struct with inside:

```
if(GLM_COMPONENT == GLM_COMPONENT_ONLY_XYZW)
    value_type x, y, z;
elif(GLM_COMPONENT == GLM_COMPONENT_MS_EXT)
    union 
    {
        struct{value_type x, y, z;};
        struct{value_type r, g, b;};
        struct{value_type s, t, p;};
    };
 else//(GLM_COMPONENT == GLM_COMPONENT_GLSL_NAMES)
     union {value_type x, r, s;};
     union {value_type y, g, t;};
     union {value_type z, b, p;};
endif//GLM_COMPONENT
```

I don't know where in the huge framework I am studying which one of the options above is actually chosen. And I don't know the meaning of all those members.
I only know that through debugging I see all those values but, as any other vec3, I use the x,y,z values for my calculations.
After this, I would like to know what actually happens if I cast an array of vec3 to an array of doubles. In practice:

```
double * cast = (double*)cx;
```

What does it give me back?

In order to understand, I tried to do this:

```
vec3 boh(1.0);
vec3 boh2(2.0);
vec3 * try = new vec3[2];
try[0] = boh;
try[1] = boh2;
double* try2 = (double*)try;
```

I realize that *try* points to the first vec3, which is boh1, so if I go debugging, I see all the x, r, s, y, g, t, z, b, p set to 1.0. Likewise try2 should be pointing to "something" related to boh1, but the debug shows me that try2 has the value 0.0078125018480932340. So, what is actually happening?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Accessing private data is undefined behaviour. You could get your `double` back, or an elephant could come out of your computer. Even worse, an elephant could come out of the computer of your clients. Don't do this.

Answer (score 0):

Officially, that is undefined behavior. It all depends what the `glm::vec3` structure contains.

I would refer to the [glm reference pages](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.7/api/index.html). They clearly explains what `glm::vec3` is and how to use it.

Comment: If `vec3*` is a POD and `value_type` is `double`, there’s not necessarily a problem with this code.

Comment: @KonradRudolph If and if :)   To be sure, the only way is to look into the source code. My answer still stands : it is better to refer to the library's documentation, and avoid such casts. The documentation is not poor in this case.